# Inner class needs access to outer class. Is it good?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, object

I have class

```
class TournamentManager
{
    public List<Target> Targets = new List<Target>();
    public List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();
    public List<Club> Clubs = new List<Club>();
    public List<Round> Rounds = new List<Round>();
}
```

Now there is problem.
Many Round functions need access to all Players and Clubs list.
Also. There are functions in Player Class that need access to Rounds list.

How to solve this? I know I didn't show much. But I would rather read some general rules. How to organize it? Should I be passing reference to TorunamentManager to those methods of Player and Round that need access to those list? Should I organize it totally different?

I'm new to OOP and that kind of programming. I also can't find any good books that would show me some how to solve problems like that.

Comment: This tells me you have a problem in defining your hierarchy. It would be best to at least list a few of the problematic functions. That way we can tell which go where.

Comment: Could you have a method in the class TournamentManager that references both Rounds and Players rather than Round needing direct access to Players.

Comment: @Blam Isn't that bad to have too many methods in one class? That is why I splited it that much. .... I need to learn much more.

Comment: It is a method if it is in TournamentManager or Round.  Think about Player (e.g. name and handicap) are different from things a players participates in (a round).  I generally try and separate the two but not the only (or even best) approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably organize it differently. Consider *relationships*.

What relationships are present? This is what I would look at

- A tournament has a set of rounds
- Every round has a set of teams
- Every team has a set of players

(not sure where Target fits in)

To me, this would mean that

```
public class Tournament
{
 public List<Round> Rounds { get; set; }
 public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
 public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Round
{
 public Team Home { get; set; }
 public Team Away { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nicely laid out I have removed my repetitive answer

Comment: I like your idea. I will try to think of something.

Comment: @TravisJ You might want to also note that [writable collection properties have problems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If your TournamentManager class is non-static (perhaps so that you can have multiple instances of it) and your Round and Player classes have methods that need to refer to properties of the TournamentManager class, you could pass the reference to the TournamentManager instance to the constructors of the Round and Player classes (which could then save that reference in a private field).

Also, if you don't need multiple instances of the TournamentManager class, you could make it a static class.  Then, the Round and Player class methods could directly refer to the lists.

```
public class Player
{
    ...

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        int numRounds = TournamentManager.Rounds.Count;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think I'll make it static. As I have only one TorunamentManager instance. I know that it will work. But Is is good practice?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you could organize your code and without knowing what you are trying to do and how complex your code is it is hard to recommend an implementation.  If you want your Round and Player class functions to be able to access your public lists in your TournamentManager class you will need to declare the lists as static elements. Then you can reference the lists in your other classes via TournamentManager.listName

Answer (score 1):

I will post specific code if this is what you are looking for.

I have an application with users and groups.
In user I want to add and remove groups.
And in groups want to add and remove users but want to add and remove groups.
Want one the synchronize the other.

Created a Class UserGroup and a HashSet of UserGroup call UsersGroups.
Pass UsersGroups to both User and Group.
Then to get groups from User LINQ where(x => x.User = this)
And to get users  Group use LINQ where(x => x.Group = this)